# how EC2 Security Group uses group id as the value in the source column

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, security-groups

We want to setup a security group that is more specific and manageable and the concept that we came up is via:

- **sg-public-group:** allows 80/443 globally
- **sg-private-group:** just a label for the meantime
- **sg-db-group:** allows 3306/tcp for sg-public-group and sg-private-group
- **sg-access-group:** allows 22/tcp for every subnet/private group that does not have an public ip address.

And an EC2 DB instance that applies the above SGs.

And an EC2 intances for the web application that is trying to connect to the DB.

Our AWS is using subnet as a basic security and our db is not accessible in the public and you need first to access in main instance before you can access the db server.

But upon testing it didn't work. Any idea on how can we make it work?

Comment: What didn't work ?? Is something accessible that shouldn't be? Be more specific. I.e. Connection from x to y you n port z was allowed.

Comment: @Nath with the reference above here is the setup: I have a sg-subnetwork-group that will handle my 4 subnets, it will allow port 22 tcp. Then I will use sg-subnetwork-group as the source for my sg-db-group for port 3306 tcp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS security groups work as whitelists: each line is a permissive rule. Anything that is not allowed, is denied, yet what is allowed, is allowed, you can't override that in any other rule.

Roughly, security groups can allow specific inbound traffic from:

- a given IP address or IP address range;
- all instances that are assigned a given security group.

Unfortunately, you can not specify anything more complex, like "allow access from any instance that does not have a public IP" - you can only specify a source security group. As you correctly assumed, security groups listed in `Source` field can be regarded as labels.

So, in your case, configuration should be as follows:

- EC2 instances with Web applicationsh should have **sg-public-group**;
- EC2 instance with DB should have **sg-db-group** and **sg-private-group**;
- EC2 instances that require access via SSH from internal subnet only should have **sg-access-group** (yet you still need to think how to access those instances you are planning to access from).

**sg-access-from** should be set up to allow connections via 22/TCP from EC2 instances that belong to **sg-private-group**. However, it is going to be your responsibility to make sure that all EC2 instances belonging to **sg-private-group** indeed do not have any public IP addresses.

For more detail look at [AWS Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups) document:

> For each rule, you specify the following:
>
> - **Protocol**: The protocol to allow. The most common protocols are 6 (TCP) 17 (UDP), and 1 (ICMP).
> - **Port range** : For TCP, UDP, or a custom protocol, the range of ports to allow.
> - **ICMP type and code**: For ICMP, the ICMP type and code. Source or destination: The source (inbound rules) or destination (outbound
>     rules) for the traffic. Specify one of these options:
>
>   - An individual IPv4 address. You must use the /32 prefix after the IPv4 address; for example, 203.0.113.1/32.
>   - (VPC only) An individual IPv6 address. You must use the /128 prefix length; for example 2001:db8:1234:1a00::123/128.
>   - A range of IPv4 addresses, in CIDR block notation, for example, 203.0.113.0/24.
>   - (VPC only) A range of IPv6 addresses, in CIDR block notation, for example, 2001:db8:1234:1a00::/64.
>   - Another security group. This allows instances associated with the specified security group to access instances associated with this
>       security group. This does not add rules from the source security group
>       to this security group. You can specify one of the following security
>       groups:
>
>     - The current security group.
>     - EC2-Classic: A different security group for EC2-Classic in the same region.
>     - EC2-Classic: A security group for another AWS account in the same region (add the AWS account ID as a prefix; for example,
>         111122223333/sg-edcd9784).
>     - EC2-VPC: A different security group for the same VPC or a peer VPC in a VPC peering connection.